# Unknown attribute 'utf8' for Permit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, utf-8, activeadmin

I am working inside of ActiveAdmin controllers. I am trying to pass in my permitted_params as well as the current date and the current user that is logged in. However, whenever I submit, I am getting the `Unknown attribute 'utf8' for Permit` error.

**admin/permit.rb**

```
form do |f|
    f.inputs do
        f.input :vehicle, :collection => Vehicle.all.map{ |vehicle| [vehicle.license_number]}
        f.input :permit_id
        f.input :date_issued, as: :date_picker
        f.input :issued_by
    end
    f.actions
end

controller do
    def new
        @permit = Permit.new
        @vehicle = @permit.build_vehicle 
    end 

    def create
         #@permit = Permit.new
         vehicle = Vehicle.find_by(permitted_params[:vehicle])
         @permit = current_user.permit.build(permitted_params.merge(date_entered: Date.today, 
            entered_by: current_admin_user.email))
         @permit.update(vehicle: vehicle)
         super
    end

    def permittted_params
        params.require(:permit).permit(:permit_id, :date_issued, :issued_by, :date_entered, :entered_by, vehicle_attributes: [:license_number])
    end

    def set_permit
        @permit = Permit.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

Anybody know why I am getting this error? I am not getting this error inside my normal rails app and it is running pretty much the same code. Thanks

**Edit**

Here is the application trace

```
app/admin/permit.rb:61:in `create'
Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓","authenticity_token"=>"zw3Px+gEOvp2UDufgiBNyG0yShTHQYBIsOK+WWj7wiYkMNkR3aLku5TMBxK5b0mQoZvKr+w6YgYZVPGxURtH0A==",
 "permit"=>{"permit_id"=>"ST-5555", "date_issued"=>"2018-11-24", 
"issued_by"=>"Nate"},
 "commit"=>"Create Permit"}
```

Comment: related to this https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/2817

Comment: So i'm looking it over, and I am trying to pass in `:utf8` into my permitted_params but I am still getting the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid Permit as a model name, try using VehiclePermit.

ActiveAdmin has its own permit_params macro for strong parameters, see https://activeadmin.info/2-resource-customization.html. There is a namespace setting called :permitted_params that includes :utf8 by default so I wouldn't use that as a controller method name.

Comment: I changed all my model name so it actually is vehiclepermit. However do you know of a fix for my UTF8 problem? Because I still can't get it to work.

Comment: Extended my reply.

Comment: That was it. Thank you very much for your help! I was just not passing in that last `[:vehicle_permit]` in my `permitted_params`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when I used postman.
Set headers : `enctype` `multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8`

Comment: Where do I do that, do I just put that at the top of the AA page?

Comment: How you send request to controller?

Comment: So I am adding that statement into the create method in the AA controller?

Comment: you need send request with this header ex if you send request from form: `<form enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8">`